# Calculate limits without l'Hôpital

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am trying to calculate the following limits

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}(2x+1) \ln \left(\frac{x-3}{x+2}\right) $$
and
$$ \lim_{x\to1}\frac{x}{3x-3}\ln(7-6x) $$

I can't use l'Hôpital's rule, so I am not sure how to solve it.

Comment: I don't know why the aberrance to using a nice result as L'Hospital. Anyway,  for the first limit, notice $(2x+1)\log\big(\frac{x-3}{x+2}\big)=\log\Big(1-\frac{-5}{x+2}\Big)^{2x+1}$. Recall that $(1+a/x)^x\xrightarrow{x\rightarrow\infty}e^a$. Te second can be done similarly, modulo a change of variables, or by using Taylor expansions around $x=1$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thank you. I managed to calculate the first limit. Can you explain about the second one?

Comment: use $\ln(1+x)/x\to 1$ in $0$. hint $7-6x=1+6(1-x))$.

Comment: The function in question has a singularity at $x=1$  (both numerator and numerator vanish at $1$. Use Taylor series of $\log(7-6x)=\log(7-6(x-1+1))=\log(1-6(x-1))$ to see if there are cancellations. You need to do the work to really lear:

Hint: $\log(1-x)=-\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n}(x-1)^n$

Comment: @OliverDiaz I don't think it's that fair to use the Taylor series when the L'Hospital is not allowed.

Comment: Then either you take swim as an act of Fatih or use something related, $\lim_n n^p/(1+a)^n=0$ $(a>0)$ which is studies typically in Calculus classes. transform $x=(1+a)^n$ and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

By continuity of the logarithm,

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \ln \left(\frac{x-3}{x+2}\right)^{2x+1}
= \lim_{x\to\infty} \ln \left(1-\frac5{x+2}\right)^{2(x+2)-3}\\
=\ln((e^{-5})^2)-3\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln \left(1-\frac5{x+2}\right).$$

Answer (score -3):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\left ( 2x+1 \right )\ln \left ( \frac{x-3}{x+2} \right )=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}\ln \left ( \frac{x-3}{x+2} \right )}{\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}\frac{1}{\left ( 2x+1 \right )}}=-\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{5\left ( 2x+1 \right )^2}{2\left ( x-3 \right )\left ( x+2 \right )}=-\frac{5}{2}\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\left ( 2x+1 \right )^2}{\left ( x-3 \right )\left ( x+2 \right )}=-\frac{5}{2}\cdot 4\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{2x+1}{2x-1}=-\frac{5}{2}\cdot 4=-10$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1 }\frac{x}{3x-3}\ln \left ( 7-6x \right )=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1 }\frac{\ln \left ( 7-6x \right )}{3x-3}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1 }\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}\ln \left ( 7-6x \right )}{\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}3x-3}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1 }\frac{2}{6x-7}=-2$$

Comment: Do you call this "without L'Hôpital" ?

Comment: yes............